# How to run function unknown amount of times based on variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Javascript API function which retrieves data from the endpoint. The problem here is it returns a maximal amount of 1000 records and the total record amount can be up to 300.000 records. So I need to loop this API function and constantly add '1000' to the `start` variable every time it runs. So this way the function will keep getting records until it hits the unknown **total amount** of records. Let's say this example has 300.000. Then it should loop 300 times.

The API and everything work perfectly. The only I problem I have the `start` variable doesn't add 1000 to itself after every time it has run. It should add 1000 to the variable itself and then run again, to retrieve the next 1000 records.

This is my function:

```
function loopFunction() {
  function getResponse() {

    if (typeof counter === undefined || counter === null) {
      var start = 0;
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.apiurl?start=" + start + "&limit=1000&access_token=xxx");

    // Parse data to JSON and get total
    var fact = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(fact);

    // Retrieve start number and count
    var start = data.start += 1000;
    var count = data.count;

    var runAgain = count + start;
    var counter = 1;

    return runAgain;

  }
  var runAgain = getResponse();

  console.log(runAgain);

  loopFunction();
}
}
```

When I run this function the data is retrieved and the looping part works. The only problem is the `console.log(runAgain);` keeps returning 1000 instead of 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 etc. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to declaree and initialize `counter` outside the function. Otherwise it gets reset to `1` every time you call it.

Comment: That doesn't really sound like an optimal method of getting data from an API.

Comment: `counter === 'undefined' || counter === null` will not work when `counter` is `undefined`. `undefined` and `'undefined'` aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: This is a bad design , You should look into pagination

Comment: Use a generator function if you want to do this really bad. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare start/counter outside the function as global. And use the same variable inside and update start/counter as per. Also add a condition checking data.count to exit the loop if it's the last or unknown amount is reached

```
var start;
var counter;

function loopFunction() {
  function getResponse() {

    if (counter === 'undefined' || counter === null) {
      start = 0;
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.apiurl?start=" + start + "&limit=1000&access_token=xxx");

    // Parse data to JSON and get total
    var fact = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(fact);

    // Retrieve start number and count
    start += 1000;
    var count = data.count;
    var currentStart = data.start;
    var runAgain = count + currentStart;
    counter = 1;

    return runAgain;

  }
  var runAgain = getResponse();

  console.log(runAgain);

  loopFunction();
}
}
```

Comment: you would need to add a condition checking the total data obtained to stop executing the cycle as per your businesses logic or API response